# How should I design my datalayer so I could potentially swap out nHibernate with linqToSql?

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-sql, ado.net

So I'm going with nHibernate, but want to design my datalayer so I could potentially swap out (or switch) to a linqToSql layer.

How should I go about designing this?

Should I make an interface that has all my database calls?

Something like this?

```
GetUser();
InsertUser();
```

Comment: Lol... I am just considering running away from LinqToSql and move to nHibernate, bet you cant convince me to stay?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Good Example of the Repository Pattern](https://web.archive.org/web/20110503184234/http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/10/08/the-repository-pattern.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the usage of repository pattern in this article and you may get a good idea.

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/06/08/Rhino-Commons-RepositoryltTgt-and-Unit-Of-Work.aspx